# How to create a script that stops Hive service on my cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I need to create a script shell that stops the Hive Metastore and HiveServer2 service from any node of cluster and I need to know where Hive services are hosted in my cluster in order to run this command:

`ssh nodename:ps aux | awk '{print $1,$2}' | grep hive | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill >/dev/null 2>&1`

How can I find out which nodes host the Hive services?

Comment: You tagged HDP... Use Ambari to do this

Comment: I agree with @cricket_007.  Look at  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=41812517 - "Using API to START/STOP services/host components" for Ambari.

Comment: @tk421 thanks for your answer. using Curl seems more better that what I would use.

Comment: I finally adopted this command to START/STOP hive: `curl -u $user:$passwd -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X PUT -d '{"RequestInfo":{"context":"_PARSE_.START.HIVE","operation_level":{"level":"SERVICE","cluster_name":"$clustername","servic_name":"HIVE"}},"Body":{"ServiceInfo":{"state":"INSTALLED"}}}' http://$ambariserver:8080/api/v1/clusters/$clustername/services/HIVE`

Comment: it's more short and more pratic